# What is the best way to determine if the device is tablet?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to write a method to determine if the device is a tablet or a phone. I don't need to display a different user interface depending on this. I only need information about the device, so that in the future I could send it to the metric.

On the Internet, I found many ways to determine if the device is a tablet. I have tested all these methods and they work. Of course, I could not test on all kinds of devices. So I'd like to know which is the best and most accurate way to determine if a device is a tablet.

This is a list of the methods I have been able to find:

**1)** *Use the smallest width qualifier*

in `res/values-sw600dp/attrs.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

in `res/values/attrs.xml`

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

And than:

```
fun isTablet() = context.resources.getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet)
```

I have concerns about this way. Might be worth adding a resource `res/values-sw720dp/attrs.xml` with:

```
<resources>
        <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
    </resources>
```

**2)** *Using* `TelephonyManager`

```
  fun isTablet(context: Context) =
        with(context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager) {
            this.phoneType == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE
        }
```

**3)** *Using* `Configuration`:

```
fun isTablet(context: Context): Boolean {
    return ((context.resources.configuration.screenLayout and Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)
}
```

**4)** *Using* `DisplayMetrics`:

```
 fun isTablet(activity: Activity): Boolean {
        val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
        activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)
        val yInches = metrics.heightPixels / metrics.ydpi
        val xInches = metrics.widthPixels / metrics.xdpi
        val diagonalInches = sqrt((xInches * xInches + yInches * yInches).toDouble())
        return diagonalInches >= 6.5
    }
```

Please help me find the best way that will work 100% of the time.

Comment: "Tablet" is a marketing term, not a technical term. What is your precise technical definition of "tablet"?

Comment: @CommonsWare, 600dp: 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

Comment: Those are resolutions. Do you consider a phone with a 600dp screen to be a tablet? Do you consider a television to be a tablet? Do you consider a foldable to be a tablet? Do you consider a window on a Chromebook to be a tablet?

Comment: @CommonsWare,This is what I'm trying to understand. I don't quite understand what a tablet is technically. "Do you consider a television to be a tablet?" - no. "Do you consider a foldable to be a tablet?" - no (I need a separate check to determine the foldable device, but I still do not quite understand how this can be implemented.) "Do you consider a window on a Chromebook to be a tablet?" - no.

Comment: "I don't quite understand what a tablet is technically" -- that is because "tablet" is not a technical term. It is a marketing term. Whoever is demanding that you distinguish "phone" from "tablet" is going to need to explain to you, in greater detail, what they mean by those terms. Then, and only then, will you be able to try to write some code to match what they are requesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are totally different things for the most part.

Method 1 is checking for the length of the smallest side of the device screen.  Basically it's saying a tablet is anything over 4 inches on the smallest size (which is going to be at least inch diagonal on any normal screen resolution).

Method 2 is saying that a tablet is anything without the ability to make a call.

Method 3 is checking that its at least 480x640 dp, or at least 3 inches by 4 inches.  (Which can be as small as a 5 inch diagonal).

Method 4 is measuring the diagonal exactly.  Which eliminates some of the theoretical problems on method 1, but its does a lot of pointless math (and this implementation isn't optimized).

All of this depends on what you define as a tablet.  There's no actual definition.  Method 1,3, and 4 are size based.  Method 2 is based on the idea that if it had the ability to call, you'd call it a phone not a tablet.

Assuming you want a size based solution, I'd go with 1.  It's more accurate and more extendable that method 3 (which wouldn't be able to tell a small tablet from a large), and faster than method 4 (and the corner cases where something could pass method 1 but method 4 catches them really don't happen in the real world).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to use the first and fourth method to define foldable also ? Unfortunately, I do not quite understand how to technically determine that the device is foldable(

Comment: @testivanivan I think you're going around things the wrong way.  An open foldable and a tablet are identical.  A closed foldable and a phone are identical.  Stop worrying about what we call a device, and worry instead about providing a good experience on a variety of screen sizes.  Be responsive by responding correctly to resize events.  Then you don't have to worry about device type, or split screen mode, or picture in picture or anything else they come up with.

Comment: Get a list of screen sizes of common devices, test it at each, and make sure it looks good.  Consider if when the screen size goes up a change in layout would make it look better, or be more usable.  That's all you really need to do, the exact definition of "tablet" or "foldable" aren't really important.

Comment: For me definition of "tablet" or "foldable" is important, because it's a business requirement, I have to send the device information to the server for the metric. Unfortunately, there is such a requirement and I need to fulfill it.

Comment: @testivanivan No, you need to push back on that requirement.  A developer's job is not to blindly fill requirements, part of it is to help figure out what the requirements should be.